# NumPy массивы создание нового

Tags: python, массивы, циклы, numpy

изучаю массивы в NumPy.
Не получается перенести отфильтрованные данные из одного массива в новый:

```
    import numpy as np
    scores = np.array([[20, 40, 56, 80, 0, 5, 25, 27, 74, 1],
    [0, 98, 67, 100, 8, 56, 34, 82, 100, 7],
    [78, 54, 23, 79, 100, 0, 0, 42, 95, 83],
    [51, 50, 47, 23, 100, 94, 25, 48, 38, 77]])
    for j in scores:
        a = np.array(j[j > 0])
    print(a)
```

По итоге получаю только первую строчку "[50 89 70 72 56 29 15 20]", где удалены нули в соответствии с условием цикла.

Comment: давайте с постановки задачи начнем - если вы поудаляете нули, у вас строки станут разной длины, такой numpy array, как я понимаю, невозможен

Comment: Да, я хочу удалить нули. Если сделать один из элементов массива короче по числам, то это не должно влиять на его создание.

Comment: Если вы сделаете один из подсписков короче других, то не получите массив numpy. вам сторит задуматься, зачем вам в таком случаем вообще двумерный массив numpy.